# What APIs of Vechile are included in GAS(Google Automotive Services)

Tags: android-auto, android-automotive

About GAS, there is very little information that can be found. I don't know what API definitions and support it has done for Vechile. Where can I find the function list and integration plan.

Only support these(https://developer.android.com/training/cars/google-services?hl=zh-cn), not have Vehicle-special functions.

Reference: https://www.android.com/gms/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CarPropertyManager class provided by the car library and get properties related to the vehicle or Car For Ex: GEAR_SELECTION, EV_BATTERY_INSTANTANEOUS_CHARGE_RATE, etc For more Info refer to this
[Vehicle Property ids](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/VehiclePropertyIds)

[Car property Manaager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/hardware/property/CarPropertyManager#getPropertyList())

[Sample code by Google, please check](https://github.com/android/car-samples/blob/main/car-lib/CarGearViewerKotlin/automotive/src/main/java/com/example/cargearviewer/MainActivity.kt)